# How to remove duplicate rows in pandas with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, rows

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['China', 'L', '08/06/2022 20:00', '08/10/2022 20:00'],
        ['China', 'L', '8/13/2022 00:54', '8/14/2022 00:54'],
        ['China', 'M', '8/14/2022 00:54', '8/14/2022 12:54'],
        ['United Kingdom', 'L', '8/27/2022 06:36', '8/31/2022 21:08'],
        ['United Kingdom', 'L', '9/01/2022 21:08', '09/02/2022 21:38'],
        ['China', 'D', '09/04/2022 21:38', '09/06/2022 21:38']
    ],
    columns=['Country', 'Function', 'Arrival', 'Departure']
)
```

In this case, i want to remove the consistent duplicate rows and replace the departure time with the last duplicates value, with below two conditions:

1. do not remove other duplicates that are not in consistent manner.
2. if the 'Function' column changed, do not take it as duplicate even it is in consistent manner.

So it should look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['China', 'L', '08/06/2022 20:00', '8/14/2022 00:54'],
        ['China', 'M', '8/14/2022 00:54', '8/14/2022 12:54'],
        ['United Kingdom', 'L', '8/27/2022 06:36', '09/02/2022 21:38'],
        ['China', 'D', '09/04/2022 21:38', '09/06/2022 21:38']
    ],
    columns=['Country', 'Function', 'Arrival', 'Departure']
)
```

Comment: double check the output, it's invalid python/pandas, which makes the question currently unclear

Comment: Thanks for the comment, already amended.

Comment: are the dates ordered? Which of Departure/Arrival should be used to consider the "last" date?

Comment: @mozway
Departure should be used as 'last' date

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
idx = (pd.to_datetime(df['Departure'])
         .groupby([df['Country'], df['Function']], sort=False)
         .idxmax()
       )

out = df.loc[idx]
```

output:

```
          Country Function           Arrival         Departure
1           China        L   8/13/2022 00:54   8/14/2022 00:54
2           China        M   8/14/2022 00:54   8/14/2022 12:54
4  United Kingdom        L   9/01/2022 21:08  09/02/2022 21:38
5           China        D  09/04/2022 21:38  09/06/2022 21:38
```

Comment: it works in this case, but seems like if i add in more columns it doesn't work anymore

Comment: "*doesn't work*" doesn't help ;) please provide a reproducible example that "*doesn't work*" and the matching expected output as edit to your question.